# Provide links to candidate questionnaire answers in elections

Tags: discussion, feature-request, election

Elections generally have a meta question, linked to in bold at the top of the election page with the text "The candidates answer your questions."

Can we include, in each candidate's nomination box, a link to the candidate's answer on that particular meta question, appropriately labelled?

I noticed in the [now-ongoing Puzzling election](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/election), there are some candidates whose nomination text includes a link saying something like "[My answers to the moderator election Q&A here](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/5115/13535)," which appears to have been edited in by the candidate directly.  However, when an election has no primary (e.g. the ongoing election at [Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/election)), it's impossible for a candidate to edit that in because that meta question [doesn't even get *posted* until the actual start of the voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277665/287315).

Yes, one can get to it indirectly through "meta posts" or through the bold link above the list of candidates, but the percentage of voters who figure out that the election Q&A is really just a meta question and that answers are "posts" might not be that large, even among the subset of voters who know what meta *is*.

Comment: Good idea, if you want to add a mockup, I've made something: http://i.stack.imgur.com/P0hen.png

Comment: @ShadowWizard It should be a link, not a stat.

Comment: True. Well, you can make your own, this was just an example.

Comment: Superseded by [Moderator Elections: new questionnaire UI](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362933/moderator-elections-new-questionnaire-ui).

Answer (score 5):

I had this in the question, but per [Monica Cellio's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281666/provide-links-to-candidate-questionnaire-answers-in-elections/281671?noredirect=1#comment915008_281671) am moving it to an answer:

**Yes, we should do that.**

Here's one example of what it might look like:
[image: Example mock-up]

[Here is an example query](https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzlingme/revision/517177/654182/get-a-candidates-answers-to-election-questionnaire) that can be used for finding the URL the link should point to; the site domain would be a variable in a real implementation.

Comment: I didn't mean to suggest that you move your proposed UI.  I meant that the query you linked demonstrates a way that it could be implemented, and that's the key to this answer.  Sorry if I caused you any churn.

Comment: Yeah, the first version of this answer just had the query link moved down from the question, but it looked like a rather inadequate answer.  Moving the UI mock-up down made it seem more complete, and the UI is more part of a proposed solution than it is part of the problem it solves or the high-level description of the proposed solution. Others could propose something different to implement the same high-level description given in the question.